# Amazon aws cli: assumed role returns access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am trying to use aws cli to run some commands. I do not have a user account in the target region, but I am trying to use a role called "AssumedAdministrator" which has sts:assumerole.
I can log into the aws web console OK using the "switch role" option.

but when I run a CLI command like :

```
aws --profile $profile sts get-caller-identity --region $region
```

I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/john.smith is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/AssumedAdministrator
```

Here's the Trusted Entities tied to that role:

```
AssumedAdministrator role
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I run aws cli commands

my sections in the credentials file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ##########################
aws_secret_access_key = ############################
region = ##########

[assumed-#####-admin]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/AssumedAdministrator
source_profile = default
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe due to CLIS version? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mfa-iam-user-aws-cli/  And I assume when you invoke the CLI you are setting the profile to assumed-#####-admin.

Comment: yes, $profile would be assumed-#####-admin. Do I absolutely have to use MFA?

Comment: I suspect you cannot possibly assume that role. First, it has a condition that MFA is not present (which looks like a mistake in the role and perhaps it should be true instead of false). Second, you're trying to assume that role from an IAM user but when using IAM user credentials, which are long-term, the aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent is never present, if read the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_configure-api-require.html) correctly.

Comment: Does _your_ IAM User have permission to call `AssumeRole`? You need to be permitted to call that Action, in addition to having the role trust your IAM User.